# Nested Set Model Php library

Tags: php, mysql, nested-set-model

Hi I need to use the nested set model to mange product categories on my site. Does anyoune know of some good pre-built PHP libraries for handling nested sets in MySQL?

Answer (score 4):

You could try "Baobab", it's a library I recently released.

http://www.sideralis.org/baobab/

Comment: Brilliant, I will check it out. I knew it was only a matter of time before someone with more skill than me would come out with a good object to manipulate nested sets. I will check it out and see how it goes. Thanks

Comment: Damn, where was this link yesterday? Awesome! The forum on your site is pretty thoroughly spammed though.

Comment: This library will only work if you use a standard mysqli connection. PDO is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit old, and could do with some refactoring, but I found a PHP Class "dbtree" on PHPClasses.org, which seems to do a fair job of it - http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2547-PHP-Manipulate-database-records-in-hierarchical-trees.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use a PHP ORM solution like [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.5/Behaviors/nested_set) or [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/hierarchical-data/hierarchical-data#hierarchical-data), they both support nested sets.

Comment: Doctrine page moved to here; https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/manual/hierarchical-data.html